# Can Monero provide anonymity when buying and selling NFTs?

Tags: privacy, exchange, wallet, currency-conversion, metadata

Please forgive my noobness, but I have basic questions about Monero's privacy when going between currencies.

Let's say a have two artist personas I want to sell NFTs under, but I don't want their wallets to be traceable to each other. I sell NFTs in a different currency (maybe ETH or wETH) because AFAIK there are no Monero NFT marketplaces. If my funds are in ETH originally, and then I buy XMR with that ETH, transfer that XMR to two separate XMR wallets on two separate accounts on an exchange where I can convert the XMR back to ETH (with no link to the original ETH), and then send each of those balances in ETH to separate MetaMask wallets in order to mint the NFTs...

1. Would it accomplish the goal of privacy?
2. How big of a hit should I expect to take on transaction fees (just to know if this is even practical)?
3. Any other issues I should take into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over complicating this. It's very simple actually.

Suppose you have wallet A with ETH.
Create two wallets B & C, and fund them with A using tornado cash. Do not send ETH directly to wallets b and c.

This will give you anonymity but not privacy. Privacy would mean that no one could see that you used tornada cash, so a statistical analysis could connect the tornada withdrawals.

And with regards to Monero, you only need one wallet. One wallet can support a lot of accounts and each account has a subaddress.
If you want to convert xmr to ETH, you can use FixedFloat.io (use tor or a VPN to protect ip address), and then supply FixedFloat a new subaddress you created. Funds that go to subaddresses of an account are part of the accounts balance and are not separate.
In the future, there will be an ETH-xmr atomic swap tool to further reduce fees and protect your privacy.